# Copy/Paste into Excel using the Exit event

Tags: ms-access

(Currently using Access 2003) Within my project I have a subform, frmSub, that holds the results of a query, located within a form (frmMain). 
frmSub is a subform control which contains a query instead of a form (its SourceObject property is set to "Query.qrySearch")

Using various run time counters, the query orders the results with the 'best' at top. The user can then manually select down which ever results they require, or take all the results.

What I'd like to do is provide a way to open the results in Excel (either the user selection or all the results if no selection is made). Ignoring the likely more frequently used 'create temp export .xls file' method for the now, I'm currently looking at a copy/paste method, mimiking the ctl-C/V way the user currently uses.
I have placed an ‘Open in Excel’ button in frmMain.

In the frmSub's Exit event I look at .SelHeight, returning >0 if a selection is made…

```
If Me.frmSub.Form.SelHeight > 0 Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
Else:
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectAllRecords
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
End If
```

Behind the ‘Open in Excel’ button on frmMain I have…

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With xlApp
    .Workbooks.Add
    .ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    .Cells.Select
    .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Visible = True
    .Range("a1").Select
End With

Set xlApp = Nothing
Call EmptyClipboard
```

Call EmptyClipboard calls an api based routine that clears the clipboard. 
While I realise that using the clipboard this way is likely not best practice, I’m not sure if that thought is universal if a reasonable use could be identified (It’s not expected that the user would be particularly disadvantaged here)

**Problem**
While the above works well there are issues with using the Exit event since it fires not only on clicking the ‘Exit to Excel’ button – and an Export to Excel, here, causes issues if the clipboard is empty.

Is there a way to determine if it was the ‘Exit to Excel’ button that initiated the sub form’s Exit event – and trap this in that the Exit event’s code? The only events I seem to have access to in frmSub is On Exit and On Enter.

If any copy/paste method would likely remain problematic then I could look at exporting to a tmp .xls file.

Answer (score 0):

With some more time to work on this I’ve rearranged things, I think, for the better. In particular, the Exit event is now only used to store the datasheet’s selection parameters, thus shifting the Copy stage into the ‘Export to Excel’ button…

frmSub Exit event includes…

```
tmpSelHeight = Me.frmSub.Form.SelHeight
tmpSelTop = Me.frmSub.Form.SelTop
tmpSelLeft = Me.frmSub.Form.SelLeft
tmpSelWidth = Me.frmSub.Form.SelWidth
```

Behind the ‘Open in Excel’ button on frmMain there is now included…

```
If IsProcessRunning("excel.exe") Then
    If MsgBox("Excel is currently running: click Yes to view in new Excel instance", vbYesNo, "") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
End If

If tmpSelHeight > 0 Then
    Form! frmSub.SetFocus
    Me. frmSub.Form.SelHeight = tmpSelHeight 
    Me. frmSub.Form.SelTop = tmpSelTop
    Me. frmSub.Form.SelLeft = tmpSelLeft
    Me. frmSub.Form.SelWidth = tmpSelWidth
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
Else
    Form! frmSub.SetFocus
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectAllRecords 
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
End If

Me. frmSub.Form.SelHeight = 0

Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

With xlApp
    .Visible = True
    .Workbooks.Add
    .ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    .Cells.Select
    .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Range("a1").Select
End With

Set xlApp = Nothing
Call EmptyClipboard

AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
```

While things appear stable enough…
I’m still manipulating the clipboard though this is not expected to be an issue.
I could later look at using any existing Excel instance.
I could still consider exporting to a .xls file, or store in temp table & linking table to Excel, as alternative methods.